# In VS Code - Docker, Python debug executing twice?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Why does debugging python app in a docker container execute twice? The app works fine, maybe it's correct behaviour, but why is it so?

After running debug from VS Code, I get: (one execution divided into two lines for easier reading)

`(venv) user@/:  /usr/bin/env /Users/user/DEV/app/venv/bin/python /Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-azuretools.vscode-docker-1.23.3/resources/python/launcher.py 65378 -- -m gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:8082 app:server docker app-dev`

`docker exec -d app-dev python3 /debugpy/launcher host.docker.internal:65378 -- -m gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:8082 app:server`

At first I though this is maybe some parameter passing, but I also get Docker message output twice:

`The application is listening on the following port(s) (Host => Container): localhost:8082 => 8082`

`The application is listening on the following port(s) (Host => Container): localhost:8082 => 8082`

Any ideas why?

Thanks for your help!

---

Another strange behaviour (most probably correct), is that VSCode adds subprocesses do Debug Console, when hot reloading the app. But this I can understand, it exits the old process and spawns a new one under different PID, but the debug console keeps all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My main question is, why do those two commands are executed: .../launcher.py and docker exec?

Comment: Can you provide details and reproducible steps. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)